# How to use Resources/Images in .net MAUI Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-blazor

We are developing a .net MAUI app using the **Blazor **variant, no **XAML**. (.net 6)

If you put a image in the folder Resources/Images (as a MauiImage), you can use directly in XAML like

```
<Image Source="YourImage" />
```

But in Blazor, you can't use like

```
<img src="YourImage" />
```

I can't find any documentation on how to use it this way.

Workaround (Not Solution):
To load images in Blazor, we have to put in the wwwroot folder, some subfolder like img.

```
<img src="img/YourImage" />
```

But this is not using the resources folder, just a static image loaded by html.

Does anyone knows how to use it correctly?

I tried to put the image in the Resources / Images folder.
I was expecting being able to use it.

Comment: Try [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72524860/199364). Let me know if that works, for resources. I haven't worked with Razor; it is based on a doc page I link there. I *describe* what you need to do, but I don't have actual code. If you get it working, please add Your Answer below, showing the exact code that works.

Answer (score -1):

When you reference different project in blazor project, you should to use "_content" in reference.

like this:`<img src="_content/.../images/xxx.png">`

Comment: Sorry, not an answer for my question.